# Signals and effects in Angular v16

Tags: angular

I am learning how to use signals in the latest Angular. Specifically, I am stuck on Effects. I see that I can create an effect in that way:

```
effect(() => console.log(this.value()));
```

But how do I know when a particular signal is changed? In reality there will be more than one signal in a component.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Effects are executed only when a value of a signal inside it is changed. Consider this example:

```
export class App {
  name = 'Angular';
  foo = signal('foo');
  bar = signal('bar');

  constructor() {
    effect(() => {
      console.log(this.foo());
    });

    effect(() => {
      console.log(this.bar());
    });

    effect(() => {
      console.log(this.foo(), this.bar());
    });
  }

  changeFoo() {
    this.foo.set('foo' + Math.random().toString());
  }

  changeBar() {
    this.bar.set('bar' + Math.random().toString());
  }
}
```

When `changeFoo` is called, only the first and the third effect will be called, because both of them are referencing `foo`. The second effect which logs value of `bar` won't be executed, as it doesn't reference `foo`.

Comment: So, when the third effect is called, how do I know which particular signal was changed? foo or bar?

Comment: I'm not aware of any way to find out which signal was changed. If you would like to react to changes in foo and bar AND know which one was changed you should probably register two separate effects (like to first and the second in the example). If you don't care which one was changed then the third one from the example is gonna work.

Answer (score 0):

Effects always run at least once. When an effect runs, it tracks any signal value reads. Whenever any of these signal values change, the effect runs again. Similar to computed signals, effects keep track of their dependencies dynamically, and only track signals which were read in the most recent execution.

See https://angular.io/guide/signals#effects